# Hot to get intersection of tuple type elements' keys?

Tags: typescript

```
type Tuple=[{a:string,x:string,z:string},{b:string,x:string,z:string}]
type IntersectionOfTupleElementKeys<T>=...
type MyType = IntersectionOfTupleElementKeys<Tuple> // = ('a'|'x'|'z')&('b'|'x'|'z')='x'|'z'
```

I have a tuple type with common fields on each element type (such as type `Tuple`'s `x and z`). How to get the intersection of the common fields (`'x'|'z'`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query keys of tuple item type:

```
type IntersectionOfTupleElementKeys<T extends readonly any[]> = keyof T[number];

type MyType = IntersectionOfTupleElementKeys<Tuple> // 'x'|'z'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmANtAvFA2gbygQwFxQDOwATgJYB2A5gDRQAeBx51dAXk6ZVVAL53YARpxa0GI7uwnU+AXQBQ80JCgBJCsAglCEAMbAyAewoB5AGbwkEAKLIAthA0BpCCEIAeGFAj1NFACaEUCQQOP7GiCC4FCDosgB8UGgA1q6GZrDoFHB2glqyANyKytAAsiAw4KhqGlo6+kamFgjIthAOzq4elsiJAPR9UADk9EMAPkNsQ0A)

---

We get the union of all tuple item types by using `T[number]`, then `keyof` applied to union type produces intersection of their keys.

Comment: Simple and greet!